# How to convert AWS Lambda to create an image for AWS Batch

Tags: java, docker, aws-lambda, dockerfile, aws-batch

Currently have java lambda code packaged as .zip files and deployed to **AWS Lambda**, but needs to move to **AWS Batch** due to long running tasks that exceed the [15 minute lambda quota](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html)

It is possible to deploy the java lambda code using container images with the docker CMD set to the handler in the Dockerfile (e.g. https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-lambda-java).

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/java:11

# Copy function code and runtime dependencies from Gradle layout
COPY build/classes/java/main ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY build/dependency/* ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/lib/

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "com.example.LambdaHandler::handleRequest" ]
```

So the code can still be deployed to AWS Lambda as a container image. Problem is it's still a lambda, so using that image for AWS Batch makes no sense right...

Gurus Given that the lambda logic is tried and tested:

1. What is the simplest way to convert the lambda code with the handleRequest method to work with AWS Batch -> perhaps execute from a JAR and to prepare an image so that in can work with AWS Batch?
2. There would need to be a **main method** for an entry point instead of the handler?

Answer (score 0):

Lambda container images are for custom environments that need to run on AWS Lambda. Functions built as container images should still follow Lambda’s invocation model, so the functions will still have a 15 minute max duration. It's not a replacement for ECS.

To use your function with Batch, you will have to build a docker image with the function's code and all dependencies, push it to ECR, use it with ECS, and use Batch API's SubmitJob for invocation with environment variables if necessary.

Yes, you will need an Entrypoint/other CMD instead of the LambdaHandler depending on your logic. Just anything that runs the function and exits the container with `CODE 0`

Comment: The lambda handler interface has an event and context object, what's the equivalent for those being available by putting the function code as part of the docker image? e.g. how would a java main function suffice as that only takes string args

Comment: Batch allows passing environment variables to the containers. You can either use lambda to pass the event and context objects as environment variables for batch to continue processing the job or pass the function arguments directly without using lambda at all

Answer (score 0):

I tried this for a python lambda and it seems to be working fine:

Take the standard lambda base image (e.g public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8). It has a predefined argument `["entrypoint.sh"]` set as the docker image ENTRYPOINT, so when using it for a "non-lambda" purpose you'll need to override that (set it to []) and pass the Command you want.

I did the overriding of ENTRYPOINT in my Dockerfile so that it can be shared with AWS Batch tasks. When called from lambda infrastructure I explicitly set ENTRYPOINT back to `["entrypoint.sh"]`.

Overriding Entrypoint does feel a wee bit hacky.